# Calling REST Web Service Using OAuth 2.0 from Apex

Tags: apex, rest, oauth2

Any good examples of calling a rest web service using OAuth 2.0 from Apex?

Comment: Downvote from me because of lack of research.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Salesforce documentation on REST callouts using Apex. There are some examples there on how to implement a REST callout.
Then use a [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&language=en_US&type=0) to handle the OAuth part of the callout, you don't need specific code for that.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest

Comment: Named Credentials are awesome! High security in an easy to use interface.